# get id and value from all input elements and pass them through ajax

Tags: php, javascript, arrays

I have a bunch of input text boxes that I want to put in an array (id and value) and pass through ajax.
After it is passed to my php code I need to loop through it and save the id and value in the database. (1 row for each id)

```
$("input").each(function() {
    values[$(this).attr("id")] = $(this).val();
});
```

I use this to get the values and create an array this is what it looks like
    {"1":"new","2":"edit","3":"save","4":"delete"}

I then pass this through ajax, but how do I loop through these values and save them?

```
$taal = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['taal']);
$arr = $_POST['values'];
foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
    $query = "INSERT INTO words (taal_id, number, word) VALUES ('" . $taal . "','" . $key . "','" . $value . "')";
    $result = $mysqli->query($query) OR die(mysql_error());
}
```

That is what I tried to use but it doesn't work

ajax request

```
$.ajax( {
    url: "javascript/ajax/taal.php?wat=saveWoorden",
    type: "POST",
    data: {values : values, taal : $('#talen').val()}
}).success(function() {
    $('.talenInfo').html('success');
})
```

Comment: What exactly doesn't work? Is it an SQL error? A PHP error? A Javascript error? Are you sure the AJAX request is getting to the server? Please show more of your code - both PHP and Javascript

Comment: Sorry, the problem is with the loop i use to go through the values. So it's the php script that doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of sending individual insert statement better to send the prepared insert statement or  post the XML data which can be handled in db side for bulk insert.

You can prepare the xml or bulk insert statement like this

```
var query = 'INSERT INTO words (taal_id, word)   ';
$("input").each(function () {
    query += 'Select  ' + $(this).attr("id") + ',' + $(this).val() + '  UNION ALL  ';
});

alert(query);
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure ... I am able to completely replicate your problem but I have tried to do so

```
<?php
unset($_POST['data'][0]);
print_r($_POST);
?>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript></script>

<script type='text/javascript'>

  $(document).ready(function()
  {
     $('#submit').click(function(){
     var values = [];


      $("input").each(function() {
      values[$(this).attr("id")] = $(this).val();
      });     

     $.ajax({
     url      : 'try.php',
     data     : {data:values},
     type     : 'POST',
     success  :function(data){alert(success)}
    });
   });}); 
         </script>
               <html>
               <body>
                <form method='post'>
               <input id='1' value='text1'  type='text'/>
              <input id='2' value='text2' type='text'/>
              <input type='button' id='submit' value='submit'/>
             </form>
              </body>
               </html>
```

what I found is the index 0 in values array is getting empty value so I have to unset It .
Make sure that you are also not having same problem because it might violate the database constraint.

DEBUG TIP : print the query to check what values are going on and try to run the query directly in phpmyadmin.. You might come to know what is the error.

You can check the firebug console to get the values that are being posted .

Answer (score -1):

From your code I understand that you are just storing the query in a variable and not executing it. You need to execute the SQL query in each loop iteration. If you are using mysql you can do it as follows:

```
mysql_query($query);
```

But please ensure that you have initialized the DB connection first.

Answer (score -1):

**HTML:**

```
<input type="text" name="" id="one">
<input type="text" name="" id="two">
<input type="text" name="" id="three">
<input type="submit" value="Submit" id="submit">
```

**JS**

```
var values = {};
$('#submit').click(function(){
$("input").each(function() {
    values[$(this).attr("id")] = $(this).val();

});
    console.log(JSON.stringify(values));


    });
```

You can pass a stringify of the object to the php and then use the JSON library for parse.
Check 
http://jsfiddle.net/wmrqk/

Hope it helps!

Comment: thanx, but how do i parse it and loop through it in the php script? that's the part that bugs me the most

Answer (score -1):

get values and id of all inputs and put them in an array, then stringify them

```
var values = {};
$("input").each(function() {
    values[$(this).attr("id")] = $(this).val();
});
values = JSON.stringify(values);
```

in php use json_decode and an foreach loop

```
$arr = json_decode($_POST['values']);
$result = $mysqli->query("delete from woorden where taal_id = " . $taal);
foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
    $query = "INSERT INTO woorden (taal_id, nummer, woord) VALUES ('" . $taal . "','" . $key . "','" . $value . "')";
    $result = $mysqli->query($query) OR die(mysql_error());
}
```